# GC overhead error in scala while computing strongly connected components of graph

Tags: scala, graph, group-by, garbage-collection

Can somone please look at this scala code and tell me why it throws the GC error when I call convertPass2?  It occurs in the second preprocess call on an array that is the same size as the one in the first call.  It computes strongly connected components using Kosaraju's algorithm.  I suspect that it is garbage collecting either "Gfirst", or "times" arrays before I want it to.

The input is a file containing the edges of the graph separated by a space.  Due to the low density of the graph, the edge list is converted to an adjacency list representation.

Please let me know if you need clarificaton.  Many thanks.

```
package algorithms4

import scala.io.Source
import scala.util.Sorting

object SCC {
    //Note this is Grev
    def preprocess(in: Array[Array[Int]]): Map[Int,List[Int]]={
      println(in.length)
      println("enter preprocess")
      val fir = in.groupBy(_.apply(1)).map(
          pair => (pair._1, 
              pair._2.tail.foldLeft(List(pair._2.head.apply(0)))((a, xs) => xs.apply(0)::a)
              )
          )
       /*println("begin computing singles")
       val singles = for{
         k <- (1 to 875714).toSet diff fir.keySet 
       } yield (k, List())
       fir ++ singles*/
       fir
      //in.foldLeft(Map((in.head.apply(0),in.head.apply(1))))((a, xs) => a+(xs.apply(0), xs.apply(1)))

    }
    def convertPass2(in: Array[Array[Int]], times: Array[Int]): Map[Int, List[Int]]={
      val edges = for{
        pair <- in
      } yield Array(times(pair.apply(1)), times(pair.apply(0)))
      println(edges.length)
      preprocess(edges)
    }



    def DFS_loop1(G: Map[Int, List[Int]]) ={
        var t = 0
        //println("GSIZE")
        //println(G.size)
        //val itr = G.keysIterator
        val times = new Array[Int](875714+1)
        val explored = new Array[Boolean](875714+1)
        for (i <- 875714 to 1 by -1){
          if (!explored(i)){
            def DFS1(i:Int): Unit={
              explored(i) = true
             if(G.contains(i)){
                 for(j <- G(i)){
                   if (!explored(j)){
                    DFS1(j)
                   }
                 }
             }
             t+=1
             times(i) = t
            }
            DFS1(i)
          }
        }
        times
    }
    def DFS_loop2(G: Map[Int, List[Int]]): Array[Int] ={
        val leader = new Array[Int](G.size+1)
        val explored = new Array[Boolean](875714+1)

        var s = 0
        for (i <- G.size-1 to 1 by -1){
          if (!explored(i)){
            s = i
            def DFS2(i:Int): Unit={
             leader(i) = s
             explored(i) = true
             if(G.contains(i)){
                 for(j <- G(i)){
                   if (!explored(j))
                     DFS2(j)
                 }
             }
            }
            DFS2(i)
          }
        }
        leader
    }
    def computeSCC(leaders: Array[Int]) ={
      val leadersMap = (1 to leaders.length-1).toList.groupBy(
          i => leaders(i)
       )
       leadersMap.keySet.groupBy(
         leader => leadersMap.apply(leader).length 
       )
    }
}

object Main extends App {
  val scc = SCC
  def source = Source.fromFile("SCC.txt")
  def Gfirst = source
  .getLines.toArray
  .map(e => e.split("\\s").map(c => c.toInt))
  source.close

   println(Gfirst.length)   
      //.map(e => List(List(e.head), e.tail))*/
   val G = scc.preprocess(Gfirst)
   println(G.apply(1))
   println(G.apply(2))
   println(G.size)
   val times = scc.DFS_loop1(G)

   val G2 = scc.convertPass2(Gfirst, times)


}
```

And the output:

```
5105043
5105043
enter preprocess
List(860482, 851820, 846832, 832536, 827774, 801801, 776406, 758955, 758952, 734309, 734061, 732157, 707710, 707709, 699074, 693575, 692316, 675019, 664635, 637921, 637920, 601113, 572229, 572219, 541482, 540151, 535063, 535062, 495884, 461693, 448071, 429291, 415833, 395686, 395685, 395684, 395683, 395682, 395681, 395680, 395679, 395678, 395677, 386605, 361757, 361755, 361754, 361753, 361752, 361751, 361750, 361749, 361748, 361747, 361746, 361745, 361744, 361743, 361742, 348061, 348060, 348059, 348058, 348057, 348056, 348055, 348054, 348053, 348052, 348051, 348050, 348048, 348047, 348046, 348045, 348044, 348042, 348041, 348040, 348039, 348037, 348034, 348033, 348032, 348031, 347563, 347562, 347561, 347559, 347557, 320270, 320269, 318620, 313976, 313160, 307630, 307629, 307628, 307627, 307625, 307624, 307622, 303372, 303371, 303370, 303369, 303368, 297779, 280871, 280787, 240432, 224091, 212295, 212294, 212293, 212292, 212291, 212290, 212288, 212287, 212286, 212285, 212284, 212283, 212282, 176667, 176664, 176663, 176662, 176661, 176660, 176659, 176658, 176657, 171188, 171182, 171179, 171178, 171177, 171176, 171175, 171172, 171170, 171169, 171168, 133568, 124673, 124672, 115401, 115399, 115355, 115342, 115336, 115314, 110442, 110441, 110440, 110439, 110438, 110437, 104822, 104821, 104820, 104819, 104818, 104817, 104815, 104814, 104813, 104812, 104809, 104791, 104790, 104789, 104788, 104787, 104786, 104784, 104783, 104782, 104772, 88665, 88664, 71113, 53211, 53206, 3121, 36, 35, 34, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 13, 12, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 1)
List(1)
714547
5105043
5105043
enter preprocess

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.updated0(HashMap.scala:328)
at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.updated0(HashMap.scala:326)
at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.updated0(HashMap.scala:326)
at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap.$plus(HashMap.scala:57)
at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap.$plus(HashMap.scala:36)
at scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:28)
at scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:24)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:224)
at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:403)
at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:403)
at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:403)
at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:403)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
at algorithms4.SCC$.preprocess(SCC.scala:14)
at algorithms4.SCC$.convertPass2(SCC.scala:40)
at algorithms4.Main$delayedInit$body.apply(SCC.scala:133)
at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
at algorithms4.Main$.main(SCC.scala:111)
at algorithms4.Main.main(SCC.scala)
```

Comment: well, it can be solved with the following two flags -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit , not sure which one exactly is doing it.  But that's not the question.  The question is why is it a GC problem?

Comment: Can you post your input file SCC.txt to pastebin or something? It would help in reproducing the issue.